# Calling Woocommerce api for react native

Tags: react-native, woocommerce

How to just use Woocommerce apis in a react native project? i am using this right now but not working showing

> jquery.default.params is not a function

if someone is using some different method then please let me know. i have been searching a proper answer for 4 days. can not find a working solutions.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Oauth from 'oauth-1.0a';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

const ck = 'ck_1016a589b1b78a8a8f17557b6f92ba2fbc65ba8b';
const cs = 'cs_d8ae64ce63e463c63ffc622d7d0b79c090b16106';
const baseURL = 'https://192.168.0.102/wordpress';

const Woocommerce = {
  getProducts: () => {
    // return makeRequest('/wc/v3/products');
    return makeRequest('/wc/v3/products');
  },
  getProductByID: id => {
    return makeRequest('/wc/v3/products/' + id);
  },
};

function makeRequest(endpoint, method = 'GET') {
  const oauth = getOauth();

  const requestData = {
    url: baseURL + endpoint,
    method,
  };

  const requestHTTP =
    requestData.url + '?' + jQuery.param(oauth.authorize(requestData));

  return axios.get(requestHTTP);
}

function getOauth() {
  return Oauth({
    consumer: {
      key: ck,
      secret: cs,
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: function (base_string, key) {
      return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key));
    },
  });
}

export default Woocommerce;
```